# GIT - Changes in a branch gets reflected in another branch

Tags: git

I created a new branch called "feature" and when I make any changes in this new branch called "feature" it also gets reflected in the "master" branch.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What does "gets reflected" mean? I guess you mean that unstaged changes are persisted when you switch branches? If so, yes, that's how git works.

Comment: yes, will the unstaged changes get persisted to "master" as well? I thought the changes you do in the new branch wont affect the master branch

Comment: If you don't commit them to master then *no*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is (reasonably common) misunderstanding:

If you switch branches in git, any uncommited changes (changes you made to files in your working directory, and did not commit) will remain untouched. Thus when you switch branches, it looks like these changes are "following you" through the branches.

In reality, the changed files are simply staying put, waiting to be committed (or discarded).

You should normally not work with uncommitted files for a long time in git. Either make a commit (which you can later discard if the changes were only temporary), throw the changes away, or ignore them.

Comment: It helps to not think of uncommitted changes to be on any branch. They are simply changes in the working directory. They don't belong to any branch until you commit them.